# Convert byte[] to SqlBytes

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes

I want to do some testing of a SQL CLR procedure and I'm trying to replicate it in a local C# project for better debugging.

I need to convert the data returned from the database to `SqlBytes` in order for my C# function to accept it but it tells me that I can't implicitly convert it. Note that the SQL column is of type `image`.

Code:

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con); //query gets a field from the database of type 'image'
        SqlCommandBuilder MyCB = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("Image");
        byte[] MyData = new byte[0];
        da.Fill(ds, "Image");
        DataRow myRow;
        myRow = ds.Tables["Image"].Rows[0];

        MyData = (byte[])myRow["econtents"];
        SqlBytes SQL = (SqlBytes)MyData; //Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte[]' to 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBytes'
```

I've tried a few different options/syntaxes for the last line and also just passing `MyData` into the method directly.

I've been following [this Microsoft article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/309158/how-to-read-and-write-blob-data-by-using-ado-net-with-visual-c-net) but it's not quite the same as my scenario. For reference I want to pass the data returned from the SQL query to: `public static SqlString WriteToFile(SqlBytes binary, SqlString path, SqlBoolean append)`

How do I perform this conversion, or is it only possible to pass in `SqlBytes` when using a CLR function from the SQL side?

Comment: The image datatype has been deprecated in favor of varbinary (max) for more than a decade now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple - you pass your byte array to the overloaded [`SqlBytes` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.data.sqltypes.sqlbytes.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Data_SqlTypes_SqlBytes__ctor_System_Byte___):

```
var bytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var sqlBytes = new SqlBytes(bytes);
```

This constructor "initializes a new instance of the SqlBytes class based on the specified byte array".